# How to set global viewmodels in ASP .NET Core 3.1?

Tags: asp.net-core-mvc, asp.net-core-3.1, asp.net-mvc-viewmodel

I am new to ASP.NET Core and have some trouble with binding global models and viewmodels to razor views. My application is a mixture of Web API and MVC with razor views.

**My goal**

When I open an ASP.NET MVC page, I need to instantiate a model by loading it from the database (`DbContext` service) based on an id received in a cookie. I want to use this model object globally in every view or partial view.

**Current Implementation**

I can access the cookies in action methods of page controllers, so that I have to load the model from the DbContext in every action method and bind it as viewmodel to target view. This is not practical, because I have to do this in every page controller, because I need that model object on all pages in my navigation pane.

**Idea**

I think it should be possible to access to Cookies and dbcontext within Startup.cs and bind the model object to _ViewStart.cshtml, so that it is accessible globally in every view or partial view. Even this approach were correct, I do not have any idea how the code would look like. Because I am learning Web-Apps with .NET Core by learning by doing and try and error at the moment. :(

**UPDATE**

I have a layout page `_Layout.cshtml`, which includes partial views like the `_NavPane.cshtml`. My goal is to pass a Model object to the _Layout, which is instantiated via loading from the database (I have a service `IMandantRepository` for this purpose) and dependent on a cookie.

That model object is needed on every page request. That's why it would be a better practice to load the model object outside the MVC page controllers and pass it to them (what I can not implement technically).

I tried to find a solution by myself and ended up in following interim ugly solution. Following is the content of the `_ViewStart` file. On the bottom I assign the needed global variables, which I can use in every view or partial view.

This solution has at least two disadvantages:

1. The model object is possibly loaded redundantly.
2. Too many program logic in a view file.

```cs
    @inject MyProject.Data.IMandantRepository mandantRepo
    @{
    // Main layout template
    Layout = "_Layout";

    // Define default values
    bool showAdminSection = false;
    string src = "/images/logos/nologo.png";

    // Read cookie value
    string currentMandantUid;
    Context.Request.Cookies.TryGetValue("currentMandant", out currentMandantUid);
 
    // Load mandant from the database
    var thisMandant = mandantRepo.GetMandantByUid(currentMandantUid);
    if(thisMandant is Mandant){
        src = "data:image/*;base64," + thisMandant.GetBase64Logo();
        showAdminSection = thisMandant.Abbr == "AdminMandant";
    }

    // Assing global variables to ViewData
    ViewData["CurrentMandant"] = thisMandant;
    ViewData["logoSrc"] = src;
    ViewData["showAdminSection"] = showAdminSection;
}
```

Comment: `I need that model object on all pages in my navigation page` Have you tried to put navigation in a layout page? If you'd like to generated navigation based on data stored in db, you can implement and use a custom service to query data, then you can call that service in layout and provide data for navigation menu.

Comment: @FeiHan Thank you for your answer. I have updated my question with a little explanation about the view layout and my intermediate solution. The perfect solution for me would to load the model object outside MVC page controllers and pass it to the page controller and Layout view or use it globally.

Answer (score 1):

This is an example code in **ConfigureService()** of `Startup.cs`. You can register your `dbContext` class in this way.

```
services.AddDbContext<BookStoreContext>( options =>
        options.UseSqlServer(_configuration.GetConnectionString("DefaultConnection")));
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I updated my question with an intermediate solution, which is not the best practice. I guess a better solution could be as follows withing the Confiure() method in Startup.cs





string mycookie = app.ApplicationServices.GetService<HttpContextAccessor>().HttpContext.Request.Cookies['myCookie'];
            var myModel = app.ApplicationServices.GetService<IMandantRepository>().GetMandantByAbbr(mycookie);
            
// How to inject myModel to _Layout.cshtml or access to it from the _Layout.csthml???

Comment: Forget the idea about adding code into Startup.cs in my last comment. It is beginner mistake. Startup methods are executed only once, when the web application host starts. :) I believe I need a middleware which reads the cookie and sets the global model object. But the open question is how to pass the global object to the _Layout.cshtml...